# SQL update variable number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I am representing data from sports matches, where each match has any number of lineups (basically teams), and any number of players in each lineup.

I have the following tables/columns:

*match* (id, start_time)

*match_lineup* (id, match_id, score)

*lineup_players* (id, lineup_id, player_id) - where lineup_id is a foreign key on match_lineup.id

*players* (id, name)

My question is about updating the *lineup_players* table. The number of players associated with each lineup (lineup_id) is variable.

When the required UPDATE to lineup_players has the same number of rows (players) I can do the following:

```
WITH new_lineup (rn, new_player_id) AS (
VALUES 
(1, 5),    -- assuming their are 5 players on the old_lineup and 5 players on new_lineup
(2, 6),
(3, 4),
(4, 8),
(5, 7)),

old_lineup AS (
SELECT (id, lineup_id, player_id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn)
FROM lineup_players
WHERE lineup_id = 10),     -- Update lineup of lineup_id = 10

UPDATE lineup_players
SET player_id = new_player_id
FROM new_lineup
JOIN old_lineup USING (rn)
```

This won't work when the number of rows (players) associated with the lineup (lineup_id) is changing on the update.

- If the number of rows (players) associated with the lineup is increasing (i.e. there is an extra player on the lineup) then I need to insert the extra rows (players).
- If the number of rows (players) associated with the lineup is decreasing (i.e. a player is being removed from the lineup) then I need to delete any extra rows.

I could accomplish this by simply deleting all rows with a given lineup_id and then inserting the new players again, but that seems kinda dirty.

I'm sure this is a solved problem in SQL but I haven't been able to find a solution online.

I'm using postgres if that makes any difference (could this be super easy to solve with UPSERT in 9.5?)

Comment: _"deleting all rows with a given lineup_id and then inserting the new players again"_ is the correct approach. It is simple, clean and effective.

Comment: @Turophile this will increment my postgres serial unnecessarily. Is that a concern?

Comment: `lineup_player` is only a join table, right? You never actually use `lineup_players.id` do you? So why care if the value changes? In fact, why have that column at all? `lineup_id, player_id` should be unique and thus can be the PK.

Comment: Your question is actually about data modelling. The association between `match` and `match_lineup` (and what they represent) is not clear from the text. I would prefer real DDL, leaving the  textual description for your intentions.

Comment: @joop I'm away atm, but a match has a list of teams, each with a list of players. So the data for each match is a list of lists.

Comment: It is obvious that you cannot update non-existent rows; so you'll have to insert them. hint: use `RETURNING` ; and chain the insert (and delete).

Comment: @janderson You shouldnt worry for postgres serial.